# Apache Phoenix JDBC driver not found on spark executors

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-phoenix

I'm connecting to apache phoenix via thick client and have already provided phoenix-client.jar to --files but still executor is unable to find the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is how spark load driver class automatically on driver and executor nodes ?

Spark look for the `java.sql.Driver` file user `META-INF` directory in all the jars added to it’s classpath. This file contains the driver class name, spark reads and load them by itself.

In the phoenix client jar, java.sql.Driver file in `META-INF` was missing, so I created the file `java.sql.Driver` with content `org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver`

and placed under `META-INF` directory and re-created the jar.

By putting this updated jar, spark was able to load the driver by itself.